# How to make http post calls synchronously in Angular 12

Tags: angular, http-post, synchronous, rxjs-observables

I have a requirement to call an API using post method, depending on the response i need to further implement business logic.
Below is code snippet:

```
GetSuffixList(_LinesToMove: string[], NbrOfLinesForMove:string): void {
      let getSuffixReq = {
      sys: this.workItemGetResponse.getTagValue("SYS"),
      icn: this.workItemGetResponse.getTagValue("ICN"),
      suffix: this.calculateFinalizeResponse.body.srvcRspn.icnSufx,
      ClaimType: this.workItemGetResponse.getTagValue("CLMTYP"),
      authEngTkn: this._service.authToken.token,
      adjId: this._service.loginRequest.UserId,
      LinesToMove: _LinesToMove,
      NumberOfLinesToMove: NbrOfLinesForMove
    };
     this._service.GetSuffixList(getSuffixReq).subscribe(
      getSuffix => {
         this.getSuffixListResp = getSuffix;
        console.log(getSuffix);
      },
       err => {
        console.log("Error at GetSuffixList");
        console.log(err.error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Challenge here is it executes asynchronously and in main component it continues executing remaining lines of code which requires response of the above called API.
May be lack of knowledge i was not able to achieve it.
Please someone help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy solution using rxjs lastValueFrom() with async await.

lastvalueFrom: Converts an observable to a promise by subscribing to the observable, waiting for it to complete, and resolving the returned promise with the last value from the observed stream.

This replaced the .toPromise() method. I was always a fan of converting my httpClient subscription's to promises, since your not really subscribing to a RESTful endpoint.

You can even throw a .catch() after, since lastValueFrom returns a promise! That is also the reason you get to use await ;)

Hopefully this helps!

```
import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

async yourFunction(){

  let getSuffixReq = {
      sys: this.workItemGetResponse.getTagValue("SYS"),
      icn: this.workItemGetResponse.getTagValue("ICN"),
      suffix: this.calculateFinalizeResponse.body.srvcRspn.icnSufx,
      ClaimType: this.workItemGetResponse.getTagValue("CLMTYP"),
      authEngTkn: this._service.authToken.token,
      adjId: this._service.loginRequest.UserId,
      LinesToMove: _LinesToMove,
      NumberOfLinesToMove: NbrOfLinesForMove
    };

  const getSuffix = await lastValueFrom(this._service.GetSuffixList(getSuffixReq)).catch(err => {console.log(err)});
  
 /* Whatever logic here will happen after the http request  */
  
}
```

Docs: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/lastValueFrom